# require two-step verification for Azure subscription administrators

Tags: authentication, azure

How can I enforce that all Azure subscription administrators have two-step verification enabled. For example, as an owner of a private GitHub repository, I can [audit](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-01-29-audit-org-members-for-2fa/) if everyone is using two-factor authentication. I want to do the same thing as an Azure subscription owner. Even better, I would like to require it.

Adding two-step verification to a Microsoft Account is easy as going to https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage and clicking `Turn on two-step verification`. I just want to make sure everyone has done this.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will have a way to see Security settings like 2-factor Auth for someone's Microsoft Account, even if he is a co-admin of a subscription.

You may want to look at organization accounts described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sign-up-organization/?rnd=1) since that possibly could have [a way to see settings for all users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj713614.aspx).